# HTML/CSS Text Not aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and my text won't align to the center for the index-intro h1!

```css
.index-intro {
width:100%;
background-color: #00C8FF;
height: 20px;
float:center;
}

.index-intro h1 {
font-family: tpeb;
font-size: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section> 
    <div class="index-intro">
        <div class="wrapper">
         <h1>Welcome to Anime!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And thanks :)

Comment: For the index-intro h1!

Comment: Use `text-align: center` for `.index-intro` instead of `<h1>` and **float: center**, seriously ?

Please study basics of [**HTML**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [**CSS**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) which will be much better for you if you're working on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trimmed down set of HTML and CSS:

```css
.index-intro {
  background-color: #00C8FF;
  text-align:center; 
}

.index-intro h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}
```

```html
<div class="index-intro">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Welcome to Anime!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This aids the vertical alignment issues too, since you had fixed the height of the containing `<div>`.  Although I guess you may have wanted that?

Here it is with some padding thrown in:
https://jsfiddle.net/9a3b4f7g/1/

Comment: Hey, Thanks it worked but sadly I cannot make the .index intro smaller now. Know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code snippet

```css
.index-intro {
        width:100%;
        background-color: #00C8FF;
        height: 20px;
        text-align:center          
       }

   .index-intro  h1 {
        font-family: tpeb;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;          
        }
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="index-intro">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Welcome to Anime!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Css is okay.

Just add this class in style tag

```
<style type="text/css">
  .wrapper
  {
  text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, you can do what you're looking for with just

```
.index-intro h1 {
font-family: tpeb;
font-size: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align:center; /*this makes the text go in the middle*/
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
background-color: #00C8FF; /*your bar color*/
padding-top:20px;  /* this "fattens" the blue bar topside */
padding-bottom:20px; /* this "fattens" the blue bar bottomside */
}
```

What this basically does is, 'make a blue bar that fits 100% the window width, with text in the middle, fatten it top and bottom'. It's better to keep your CSS simple like this if you can. Keeps you from getting confused in the long run.